# Windows Store app search keywords

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

Our company (DriveHQ) has published a few apps on Windows Store. However, when searching apps in the Store using our company name "DriveHQ", we can only find two apps whose names contain "DriveHQ" - DriveHQ FileManager and DriveHQ WebDAV Service; the other two apps are named as Webcam Security Camera and CameraFTP Cloud Security Camera Viewer.

So my question is: in order for users to find an app by searching the company name, do we have to include the company name in the app name?

Answer (score 0):

The choice is yours:

If you don’t want to change the name of your app, you can add your company name to the keywords in the Store listing that are not displayed to customers but can help your app appear in search results related to your company name.

If you want to include your company name in the app “Webcam Security Camera” and “CameraFTP Cloud Security Camera Viewer”, you might have to think about keeping your app name short since the space to display your app’s name is limited in many places. Then you need to create a new submission for it and please make sure that the new name is used in the **Package/Properties/DisplayName** element in the app manifest file, and update the graphics and text including your app name.

You might refer to [Rename an app that has already been published](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-app-names?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#rename-an-app-that-has-already-been-published).